# Webpack can't find babel

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, babeljs

I would like start `webpack-dev-server` with hot module replacement, but i've error with babel. If i run only webpack, bundle is good.

My file config is on `.build/` folder.

[image]

Do you have any idea why i've this error ?

Thank you !

Comment: Could you please provide the webpack config and your installed modules (from package.json)? Otherwise it's hard to guess what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are using babel as compiler in your webpack and you don't have installed it so installing babel and preset es-2015 should resolve your problem.

> Note:- it is not webpack-dev-server who is complaining, it is webpack. Webpack-dev-server hob is to only serve your application to browser or may be bit more but it will not resolve any dependency for you.

Comment: Hello :) babel and preset-2015 are installed. It's i run "webpack", my bundle is compiled without error

Comment: The pick you add is showing that webpack is complaining not webpack-dev-server. And the pic is the status of your build which is not totally successful.